# Slavery verses on the bible (1 Peter 2:18-20)

Tags: bible, bible-translation, peter

Is it ok to have slavery according to bible?

> Servants, be subject to your masters with all fear; not only to the
>   good and gentle, but also to the froward.
>
> For this is thankworthy, if a man for conscience toward God endure
>   grief, suffering wrongfully.
>
> For what glory is it, if, when ye be buffeted for your faults, ye
>   shall take it patiently? but if, when ye do well, and suffer for it,
>   ye take it patiently, this is acceptable with God.

Comment: There are [a number of slavery questions](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/search?q=slavery) already on the site. Also, David found what appears to be a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It **was** certainly "okay." The Israelites owned slaves purchased with money ([Exo. 12:44](http://www.blbclassic.org/Bible.cfm?b=Exd&c=12&t=KJV#conc/44)). No explicit prohibition is ever declared of this practice in the NT. In fact, servants are commanded to obey their masters ([Col. 3:22](http://www.blbclassic.org/Bible.cfm?b=Col&c=3&t=KJV#22)).

Slavery is not inherently evil but it can be abused like most things. The Bible explicitly prohibits abusing slaves ([Exo. 21:20](http://www.blbclassic.org/Bible.cfm?b=Exd&c=21&v=20&t=KJV#conc/20)), for all men are made in God's image.

However, it is **no longer** "okay" because civil law prohibts it, and Christians are commanded to obey the authorities under which they live.